How to self-fund a PhD in STEM in europe?
I am an EU citizen graduated of two masters, interested in pursuing a biology/environmental conservation PhD in either a UK university or a European one. Last year I applied to several PhD offers and got interviewed for three different projects, two of them being in some well-established research group in my field, but I have not been selected. 
This year I am planning to apply to advertised projects again, but I am also contacting researchers directly to try to set up a project in collaboration with them. I quickly got positive replies, and I started to search some funding. 
I have ruled out being funded by a company, as my subjects of interest are unlikely to match their interests (research question example: what's the connectivity between these two populations of this ecologically important but economically unexploitable specie?) 
I would not bet on the competitive grants offered in some UK universities, as I have no peer-reviewed paper published at the moment (I know it's not mandatory but having discussed this option before with a potential supervisor it makes the project more appealing).
From country to country, I can find some research grants, but so far I haven't found any that doesn't require the application to be submitted by at least a post-doc.
To your knowledge, are there research grants that are open to non-PhD holders to fund a PhD project?
More broadly, are there ways to "self fund" a PhD project (i.e. get funding from an institution to pay your salary and eventually field/lab work during the course of a PhD project) in Europe?
I understand that there are probably as many situations as there are countries in Europe, so providing national level experience is also welcome

I believe you're just looking for funding. "Self-funding" is usually used to describe using ones personal funds.

This needs an edit to clarify the actual need. Some statements are inconsistent and seem to imply misunderstanding of how the system works. What are you really seeking, as it doesn't seem to involve self-funding as generally understood?

@patou I'm voting to close this question because it needs clarifying. "Self-funding" usually implies paying for it yourself. What I think you are actually asking is "How can I find funding myself for a PhD", but I wouldn't want to make such a big change as an edit. Do a careful check for duplicates and if you think this hasn't been answered then please edit the question to clarify, and I will be happy to support re-opening.

@Flyto Considering the answer and others comments I agree with you that this question should be closed. My first aim was to create a question that would offer a guide to students willing to undertake a PhD that in a European context:

have identified a relevant subject
have identified a potential supervisor and got it motivated to supervise such project  - Can't start the project because there is no money available but are willing to search for some.


@Buffy You mentioned possible misunderstanding of how the system works, could you bring some precisions. It may help in the search process/editing of this question, proposed by Flyto

It sounds like you're looking for sources of funding, as opposed to self-funding.
Check out the UKRI guidance on finding funding for doctoral research. You may find the funding finder particularly useful for filtering for funding types and areas that fit your needs.
If you can fit your research question into the purview of a Center for Doctoral Training (CDT) then they'll handle arranging the funding for you. Try this list of the currently available CDTs offered by NERC (the research council most likely related to your study area).
